# JSON exception error while publish. Build is a success .net 6.0.101

Tags: .net, .net-core

```
Build started...
1>------ Publish started: Project: Nop.Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to E:\projects\RidusWebApp\publishnew...
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe <compressed>
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(490,5): Error : JsonException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.StaticWebAssetsManifest.FromJsonBytes(Byte[] jsonBytes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest.PersistManifest(StaticWebAssetsManifest manifest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest.Execute()
JsonReaderException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)


1>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 11:58 AM and took 45.419 seconds ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ========`your text`==
========== Publish started at 11:58 AM and took 45.419 seconds ==========
```

trying to solve this error during publish, build is a success. Some error related to parsing a file which is a inherent .NET razor file. Please advise.

Build is a success but publish fails.

Comment: After long struggle it is noted that when i switched windows OS, windows had corrupted a file that was creating this error. Resolution is to delete your obj folder and publish. It has corrupted this file staticwebassets.build.json

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle it is noted that when i switched windows OS, windows had corrupted a file that was creating this error. Resolution is to delete your obj folder and publish. It has corrupted this file staticwebassets.build.json

Resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).